# MySQL - Select specific rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of database tables named like:

```
site_1_details
site_2_details
site_3_details
...
site_420_details
```

all tables have the same fields, like:

```
ID  | SETTING | VALUE 
----------------------
1     name      Site 1 Name
2     desc      Site 1 Desc
3     email     Site 1 Email...
...
```

(only the value fields are different)

How can I get a set of values from certain tables?

For example, I want to get the name & email values from sites 3,7 and 15. How could I do that with a SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 3 AS siteID, name, email
FROM site_3_details

UNION

SELECT 7 AS siteID, name, email
FROM site_7_details

UNION

SELECT 15 AS siteID, name,email
FROM site_15_details
```

This is a horribly bad design. Why couldn't you put a "siteID" field into a single table, which'd reduce the query to:

```
SELECT name, email
FROM site_details
WHERE siteID IN (3,7,15);
```

comment followup:

Ah well, then you just modify the individual queries:

```
SELECT 7 AS siteID, ID as fieldID, name AS fieldName
FROM site_7_details WHERE SETTING IN ('name', 'email')

UNION

....
```

Any reason you've designed the tables like this? Sounds like you're trying to implement your own database on TOP of a database engine which is already perfectly suited to doing this kind of relational data handling.

Comment: but name and email are not fields, they are records. does select work like this with records? The fields are ID/Settings/Value

Comment: but if I would use a single table for all this, this table would turn out to be huge

Comment: And? That's what databases are for - selecting specific data based on your requirements. There's MySQL databases out there with tables with literally billions of rows. A few hundred or few thousand rows is *NOTHING*.